# How to preview CKEditor content on Bootstrap modal using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I want to get an input from users using **CKEditor** `textarea` and that value should be displayed on a **Bootstrap Modal** without post back the page. I'm using **jQuery**.

How can I implement that?

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnPreview").click(function() {
    var content = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
    $('#display_div').val(content);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **jQuery**'s [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function.

```
$('#display_div').html(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant:

```
$( '#display_div' ).html(content);
```

instead of

```
$( '#display_div' ).val(content);
```